# How does shared external hive metastore depend on a specific version of HDInsight(Hadoop) cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

Lets say we have an external Hive Metastore and then we have a bunch of Hadoop (HDInsight) clusters which we are deleting and creating as and when needed for processing and these are using this shared Hive Metastore. At some stage we will start creating these clusters with newer version of HDInsight as and when the newer versions become available. Now, assuming that the external Metastore is remaining fixed during all this (it's not going to get re-created), could it create problem for the future version of HDInsight? Or every time we start using new version of HDInsight, we have to migrate the external Metastore to newer version too? How does this relation between Hive Metastore and HDInsight cluster play out?

By 'version' of Hive Metastore , I mean -- there was a point in time when the specific external Hive Metastore did not exist and then a first HDInsight(Hadoop) cluster would have been created and empty SQL Server database instance would have been specified during the cluster creation. As a part of cluster creation, the database hosting Hive Metastore would have been populated with Hive metadata. So this is what I mean by 'version' of Metastore -- probably it gets the same version as the Hive component associated with the specific HDInsight cluster version getting created.

Comment: That would all depend on the API compatibility of the metastore. For example, I'm not sure Hive 3 would work with a Hive 1.x or 2.x metastore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** When a new, higher version of Azure HDInsight is created against an existing custom metastore database, the system upgrades the schema of the metastore, which is irreversible without restoring the database from backup.

If you share a metastore across multiple clusters, ensure all the clusters are the same HDInsight version. Different Hive versions use different metastore database schemas. For example, you can't share a metastore across Hive 2.1 and Hive 3.1 versioned clusters.

For more details, refer "[Hive metastore best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-external-metadata-stores)".

Hope this helps.